# How to trace position of dropped element and place it accordingly inside div javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a big div element when I can drop my elements. Now whenever I drop some elements into target div, it will position automatically. But I want my dropped element to be kept at a position where I dropped it inside div. How can I achieve this.

I have normal function implemented as:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

How can I track a position where I dropped element so that I can place it to the same location inside div?

Comment: Did you try using any existing libraries like jQuery Drag-Drop to achive this?

Comment: No...I am fully working in JS only. :( I have some specific framework which I am using for JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of dropped element by:

```
 var x = event.clientX;
 var y = event.clientY;
 var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
```

So your final code will be:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    console.log(event.clientX);
    console.log(event.clientY);

}
```